# Cleaning up repositories in GitExtensions

Tags: git-extensions

I typically use Git Extensions more than command-line git on windows. Does Git Extensions have a way to delete or move a repo that I cloned, or do I have to do this elsewhere?

Related question: is there a way to cleanup (i.e. remove entries from) the recent repository list in Git Extensions? (including the list in the "Change working directory" drop down)

Comment: It doesn't appear that Git Extensions has any of the things I requested, unless someone knows otherwise. So I just moved the directory on the file system (since Git repos are self-contained dirs) then opened the new location in GitExt which works fine.

Comment: Answer to the related question: In the current version of Git Extensions (2.47.3), the drop down for selecting from recent repositories also contains an option to "Configure this menu". Select that and there will be lists on the right of recent repos. Right-click on a particular repo in the list and there is an option to "Remove from recent repositories". That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding "Related question" In version 2.41 There is option to remove the repositories from recent repositories .

This can be done as follows

click on the dropdown and then click configure this menu

[image: click on the dropdown and then click configure this menu]

select the repository you want to remove from repository list and click ok

[image: select the repository you want to remove from repository list and click ok]

Comment: Yes, they finally added this capability. Thanks for the screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

try edit C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\GitExtensions\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.settings

under

`<string>history remote</string>`

delete something in Repositories

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found a better way - your answer prompted me to revisit this issue with the latest version and it appears they've addressed this.

Answer (score 2):

Recent repositories are stored in the registry at

```
/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/GitExtensions/GitExtensions/history.
```

Edit or delete that key

Comment: I found the registry key and see what you mean about modifying it. Seems like that would work but it's not really something I'd want to do on an ongoing basis. So thanks though I'm not sure I'll use it :)

Comment: I didn't have the second GitExtensions folder (Windows 8, Git Extensions 2.47.3), so this did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can right click on the repository you want to delete from recent repositories list and then click on delete in the UI.

Comment: Kind of hard to do when there's 100's of them.

Answer (score 0):

First question: "Does Git Extensions have a way to delete or move a repo that I cloned?"

No. You can delete all the files, but you will be unable to delete the Git control files in the .git directory because they are open by one or more git.exe processes.

1. Open taskmgr.exe
2. find the git.exe processes running under your own user account
3. kill the process tree(s) and acknowledge the warning dialog(s)
4. Delete the repository folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was not about `git clean` but since this is the first and only Google hit coming up if anyone searches for that: Git Extensions has this under Commands → "Clean working directory...". However, [this won't include submodules](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/8011).